# How to concat blob variables in google appscript?

Tags: javascript, excel, google-apps-script, blob, spreadsheet

I am trying to concat contents of multiple spreadsheet's data and write that into a new MICROSOFT_EXCEL file.

My sample code is

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + "FILE_ID" + "&exportFormat=xlsx";
var url1 = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + "SECOND_FILE_ID" + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

var params = {
      method      : "get",
      headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
      muteHttpExceptions: true
    };

var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

var blob1 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url1, params).getBlob();

var barr = blob.getBytes();
var barr1 = blob1.getBytes();

var combine = barr.concat(barr1);

var blbfnl = Utilities.newBlob(combine);

blbfnl.setName("my_new" + ".xlsx");
DriveApp.createFile(blob1);
```

This code is creating a file in '.xlsx' format but neither google sheet nor Microsoft Excel is able to read this file.

I can't use spreadsheet for final result as has cell limitation of 10 millions.

Could you please provide a light on where am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you're attempting will not work. Concatenating two arbitrary blobs will just result in an error. Your real issue is storing large data sets, and Google Sheets are ill-suited for that purpose. You may have to migrate to a more scalable database solution - but they are not likely to be free.

Comment: Yes, rather then concatenating blobs you may want to get the data in each sheet, merge that together using JS, _then_ export the result.